# NamedQuery a Date

Tags: grails

I have this simple namedQuery below:

```
selectNullDates{
eq("birthDate", null)
}
```

But I am not getting any results. How can I namedquery a null dates?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Grails, but I think it should be:

```
selectNullDates{
  isNull("birthDate")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
selectNullDates{
  isNull("birthDate")
}
```

**Reference**

- http://grails.org/doc/1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html